# Import CSS file in Python GTK3 program created using Glade

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, user-interface, gtk

I try to find information about adding a colored button widget. I tried adding `suggested-action` as class, but the button is still grey. So i want to write my own css file with my own style information.
I'm using glade to create the glade file and build the gui from that in my main.py.

Where do I have to put the css file in my source tree and how do I import it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a HowDoI guide here: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/CustomStyle

In Python you have to first import Gdk:

```
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk
```

Then you can set the CSS at startup:

```
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
provider.load_from_path("/path/to/style.css")
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(screen, provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

Here I recommend using an *absolute* path. If you use relative paths you will get into problems if the *working directory* **is not** the directory of the project. For example, if you use relative paths, this will not work:

```
cd somedirectory
python /home/user/project/main.py
# Error: cannot find style.css
```

*NOTE*: of course, the **background-color** property only works if there is *no* **background-image** set filling the background. The Adwaita theme sets the background-image on buttons. So remove it:

```
button {
  background: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: works like a charm. for google finders: I generated the absolute path from the current directory + my relative css path.